# Alternatives to Google Scholar to follow publications of selected authors

Tags: google-scholar

I like Google Scholar's alert feature, where you can subscribe to alerts about an author's new publications.

However today I found out this feature is limited to 200 alerts. After that, I cannot follow any more authors. (Ref. [How to increase the number of authors followed in Google Scholar?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/79574/how-to-increase-the-number-of-authors-followed-in-google-scholar)).

Thus, is there any alternative service that tracks the publications of an author as well as Google Scholar? I have tried Semantic Scholar, but I find it a bit lacking (e.g., often an author will appear with multiple profiles with slight name variations). Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could try Web of Science's [Author Alerts](https://webofscience.help.clarivate.com/en-us/Content/author-alerts.html). I don't know if there is a maximum number of alerts. In my experience, WoS typically does a good job at identifying unique researchers, but it's not perfect. YMMV. The delay in indexing may or may not be an issue for you.

According to NIH Library's [Keeping Current with the Literature](https://www.nihlibrary.nih.gov/resources/subject-guides/keeping-current) page, Scopus also supports author alerts. The same level of detail is not given for EMBASE or PubMed.

Comment: How exactly do I create a search in Web of Science? I see the screenshots in that link you posted, but there is no actual link to a page where I can actually search.

Comment: @a06e Assuming you have access (presumably through your institution as it is a paid service), just go to https://www.webofscience.com/wos and switch the search mode from Documents to Researchers.